# Не срабатывает обработчик при распознавании речи (System.Speech.Recognition)

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи

Ошибок нет, но обработчик никак не хочет реагировать. 
Сам код:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine recEng = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
if (flag2)
{        
    Choices commands = new Choices();
    commands.Add(new string[] { "open", "close", "print" });

    GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
    gBuilder.Append(commands);

    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
    recEng.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);

    recEng.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    recEng.SpeechRecognized += recEng_SpeechRecognized;
    recEng.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    flag2 = false;
    listen.Label = "off";
}
else
{
    recEng.RecognizeAsyncStop();
    flag2 = true;
    listen.Label = "on";
}
```

Обработчик:

```
static void recEng_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("!");
    if (e.Result.Text != null) System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

`MessageBox.Show("!");` - не имеет никаких условий, и по логике вещей должен срабатывать в любом случае. Но этого не происходит. Вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: почему "в любом случае"? судя по названию, должен срабатывать, если что-то распозналось

Comment: А вы уверены, что движок распознает вашу речь? Попробуйте подписаться на `SpeechDetected`, `SpeechHypothesized` и `SpeechRecognitionRejected` и посмотреть, какое событие вообще срабатывает.

Comment: @andreycha Не срабатывает ни одно из них. Микрофон работает, и установлен по умолчанию(галочка стоит на нем в списке записывающих устройств).

Comment: Попробуйте тогда подписаться на `AudioSignalProblemOccurred` и `RecognizeCompleted` и посмотреть, что выводит в аргументах ([раз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.speech.recognition.audiosignalproblemoccurredeventargs.audiosignalproblem(v=vs.110).aspx) и [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: А вообще погодите-ка... У вас `recEng` -- локальная переменная. Может так статься, что сборщик мусора кушает ее быстрее, чем успевает сработать событие. Попробуйте сделать ее полем класса, либо вызвать блокирующий `Recognize()`.

Comment: @andreycha А можно в виде кода, я просто не совсем понимаю сейчас.

Comment: Добавил ответом.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `recEng` -- локальная переменная. Скорее всего сборщик мусора успевает скушать ее быстрее, чем заканчивается распознавание и срабатывает событие. Попробуйте сделать переменную полем класса, либо вызывайте блокирующий `Recognize()`:

```
public partial MyForm : Form
{
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine recEng;

    public MyForm()
    {
        // код инициализации формы
        InitializeSpeechEngine();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         // остальной код метода
         recEng.Dispose();
    }

    private void InitializeSpeechEngine()
    {
        recEng = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(CultureInfo("en-US"));
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "open", "close", "print" });

        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);

        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
        recEng.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);

        recEng.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEng.SpeechRecognized += recEng_SpeechRecognized;
    }

    private void listen_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag2)
        {
            recEng.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            flag2 = false;
            listen.Label = "off";
        }
        else
        {
            recEng.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            flag2 = true;
            listen.Label = "on";
        }
    }
}
```

Если это не поможет, подпишитесь на события `AudioSignalProblemOccurred` и `RecognizeCompleted` и смотрите, есть ли какие ошибки в аргументах ([раз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.speech.recognition.audiosignalproblemoccurredeventargs.audiosignalproblem(v=vs.110).aspx) и [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Вынес объявление переменной recEng в поле класса - ничего. Подписался на `AudioSignalProblemOccurred` - событие не срабатывает. Вот я его зарегистрировал: `recEng.AudioSignalProblemOccurred += new EventHandler<AudioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs>(recEng_Problem);`

Comment: А вот обработчик `void recEng_Problem(object sender, AudioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();

            details.AppendLine("Audio signal problem information:");
            details.AppendFormat(
              " Audio signal problem:      {2}" + Environment.NewLine +
              " Recognition engine audio position: {3}" + Environment.NewLine,
              e.AudioLevel, e.AudioPosition, e.AudioSignalProblem
              );
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(details));
            
        }`